# ¿Cómo recorrer un dataframe para calcular frecuencias de valores en varias columnas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un Dataframe con una columna identificador y 4 columnas de características de cada identificador. A continuación presento un ejemplo:

```
    Código   C1  C2  C3  C4
    333      ab  aa  cc
    222      cc
    111      mm   nn  xx  ff
    111      xx
    222      nn   mm  zz
```

Lo que requiero es recorrer el Dataframe para encontrar cuántos registros hay de cada identificador y hacer un conteo de frecuencia de las características que corresponden a cada uno, en una columna sin tener en cuenta si son características diferentes y en otra teniendo en cuenta si son diferentes. Es decir en mi ejemplo la respuesta sería:

```
    Código Apariciones Características Características diferentes
    111      2         5                  4
    222      2         4                  4
    333      1         3                  3
```

He intentado hacer lo siguiente:

Primero saque el listado de códigos eliminando los duplicados

```
    codigos = df['codigo']
    codigos= codigos.drop_duplicates()
```

Luego intente hacer un 'for' para registrar el número de características por código así:

```
 for i in codigos.values:
        datosindividuales=df[df['codigo']==i]
        apariciones=len(datosindividuales)
```

No se como continuar para encontrar la frecuencia de las características, intente con groupby pero no me arroja lo que necesito. Soy nueva en la programación. Agradezco en lo que me puedan colaborar

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar cargamos tu `dataframe` de ejemplo:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO("""Codigo;C1;C2;C3;C4
333;ab;aa;cc;
222;cc;;;
111;mm;nn;xx;ff
111;xx;;;
222;nn;mm;zz;
""")

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")
```

Lo primero que vamos a hacer, es armar una lista con los valores de cada columna por cada `Codigo`:

```
df['CN'] = df[['C1','C2','C3','C4']].values.tolist()
df = df.groupby('Codigo').agg({'CN': 'sum', 'Codigo': 'count'})
# Borramos los valores nan de cada lista
df['CN'] = df['CN'].apply(lambda x: [e for e in x if str(e) != "nan"])
# Renombramos columna
df=df.rename(columns = {'Codigo':'Apar'})
print(df)

                          CN  Apar
Codigo
111     [mm, nn, xx, ff, xx]     2
222         [cc, nn, mm, zz]     2
333             [ab, aa, cc]     1
```

Ahora simplemente hay que contar los elementos totales y los elementos distintos de cada `Codigo`:

```
df['Car.'] = df['CN'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
df['Car.Dif'] = df['CN'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
# Cosmetica: Borramos la columna de trabajo y reseteamos índice
df = df.drop('CN', 1)
df = df.reset_index()

print(df)

   Codigo  Apar  Car.  Car.Dif
0     111     2     5        4
1     222     2     4        4
2     333     1     3        3
```